# no data found in PEM block

Tags: hashicorp-vault

Hashi Vault: Attempting to set a PEM-encoded certificate and private key bundle, using the pki/config/ca endpoint. The bundle.pem is a concatenation of the ca and private key. The following is the command and output
vault write pki2/config/ca pem_bundle=@bundle.pem

What is the proper format for the pem_bundle?

Resolution attempted
1. Removed all blank lines in the bundle.pem
2. Also tried to convert pem files to a string that can be passed in json
    awk 'NF {sub(/\r/, ""); printf "%s\n",$0;}' cert-name.pem
3. Also tried the UI as well as the api interface.
4. Reviewed similar items on github regarding 'no data found in PEM block'; did not resolve issue.

vault write pki2/config/ca pem_bundle=@bundle.pem

I expect the output to be:
Success! Data written to: pki/config/ca
The actual results are 
PUT http://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/pki2/config/ca
Code: 400. Errors: * no data found in PEM block

Answer (score 2):

After further research, there is an issue with the private key formatting.

The private key needs to be changed from pkcs8 to pkcs1
 openssl rsa -in pkcs8.key -out pkcs1.key -outform pem

Then recreate bundle using the pkcs1 formatted private key.

Then the following command is successful.
 vault write pki2/config/ca pem_bundle=@bundle.pem

Comment: How did you find out that it was a pkcs8 key ?